# civiEvent calendar not showing details after php 8.1 upgrade

Tags: civievent, php, php8

Running civiCRM 5.66.0 on WP 6.3.2 upgraded to php 8.1 over the weekend.

The internal civicEvent calendar no longer displays event titles, or previous events at all.

We are also using the Event Calendar extension for a public listing and that is still working fine. We can use the manage event function to see a listing of events, but the calendar view is (was) very handy for quickly finding an upcoming event to check volunteers / registrations / etc.

The only two things I did over the weekend were upgrade from 5.65.0 to 5.66.0 and from php 7.4 to php 8.1

1. Has anyone else seen this issues?
2. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix (other than downgrading)?

[image: civiCRM calendar]
[image: external Event Calendar extension view]
[image]

Comment: Are there any error in the logs?

Comment: Not anything obvious. I'm not really sure what I'm looking for to be honest. There are some msg's about missing eid but I don't know if that's event ID or some other civicrm ref. The events are there - they're showing on the public view and in the manage event list view.

Comment: Missing eid is probably missing event id, would probably be helpful to add those to your question.

Comment: Best thing to do would be to load the calendar page with the problem, then check for errors that just came up when you do that.

Comment: Tried that, nothing new added to log. I also turned on Debug & Backtrace and opened the calendar, nothing added and no pop-ups appear.

Comment: OK - I tried inspecting the actual web page, as no errors are being thrown. It looks like the table cell has a title, but it's not visible. Which makes me suspect a css issue is rendering it either in the same colour as the cell background, or some 'invisible' colour setting. Will try digging through the style sheets. However, I've not changed the site theme recently, and civicrm should be using the site css.

Comment: Partial solution - I edited the css and the titles now show up again on the calendar entries. This was the css entry in question, the color had be set to the same as background colour. I've reset it to white here and titles are back - now just to figure out why previous events aren't showing up.      **.crm-container a, .crm-container a:link, .crm-container a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}**

Comment: Ok - that wasn't the fix I thought it was. That changed all the container text white, rendering other screens unreadable. Still searching for the css that defines the calendar element colour.